# C++ Reading lines from txt, removing white spaces and saving to new file

Tags: c++

could I ask for advice? Please, could someone give an example of code, which deletes spaces from lines of the first text file and saves "new text without spaces" into the second file. I understand how it be probably working, but I can not write it, because i am beginner in programing. Thanks for any advice.
My codes:

```
        //read csv file
         void readCSV(istream &input, vector< vector<string> > &output)
            {
                string csvLine;

                while(getline(input, csvLine) )
                {
                    istringstream csvStream(csvLine);
                    vector<string> csvColumn;
                    string csvElement;

                    while(getline(csvStream, csvElement) )
                    {
                        csvColumn.push_back(csvElement);
                    }       
                    output.push_back(csvColumn);
                }
            }


        //save all from csv to txt 
        void saveToTxt()
        {

            fstream file("file.csv", ios::in);

            ofstream outfile;
           outfile.open("file.txt");

            typedef vector< vector<string> > csvVector;
            csvVector csvData;

            readCSV(file, csvData);


            for(csvVector::iterator i = csvData.begin(); i != csvData.end(); ++i)
            {
                for(vector<string>::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j)
                {

                    outfile<<*j<<endl;

                }



//code for deleting spaces, what i found, but i can't implement to above codes, coz my programming skill are not big

                   string s;   
                          while (getline( cin, s ))
                            {
                            s.erase(
                              remove_if(
                                s.begin(),
                                s.end(),
                                ptr_fun <int, int> ( isspace )
                                ),
                              s.end()
                              );

                            cout<<s<<endl;
```

Comment: Yes, you can ask for advice. However, you are asking for someone to either review your code, or provide you with an example. That's similar to asking your neighbour for advice on a fence, and then asking "How about I take some panels from your fence and use as mine".

Comment: I believe that your current version is a little bit long. Try a simplier approach: read a character from the file. If it isn't a whitespace symbol add it to a buffer. After you read the file the buffer contains only non-whitespace symbols.

Comment: @MatsPetersson i'm sorry, i forget to " ".. yes really isnt my own code, it is code, from which i inspired.. sorry for bad context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love solutions which won't qualify as a result for a homework assignment. Below is how I would write code for the specification, partly because I genuinely think that this is how it is to be done and partly to give others a bit of interesting reading. It contains all the necessary hints to create a teacher-friendly solution, too:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::remove_copy_if(
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::ifstream("in.txt").rdbuf()),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
        std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::ofstream("out.txt").rdbuf()),
        [](unsigned char c){ return std::isspace(c) && c != '\n'; });
}
```

If you can't use a C++ 2011 compiler you'll need to replace the lambda function by an actual function with the same signature.

Comment: Genuinely curious. It is more efficient to to hit the stream buffs by reference directly rather than using `istream_iterator` and `ostream_iterator` ? I would think it is, but you're no-doubt experienced with both whereas I have only used the latter.

Comment: @WhozCraig: The primary reason I'm using `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` is that it doesn't skip whitespaces and it seems newlines are to be retained! If all whitespaces, including newlines, are to removed, you could just use `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(in), std::istream_iterator<char>(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(out));`. This doesn' answer your question, though. To answer your question: stream buffer iterator are a lot faster than stream iterators. When actually processing large files it doesn't really matter because I/O will dominate the processing time.

Comment: @WhozCraig: The stream buffer iterators just access the stream buffer's buffer. Using algorithms which are optimized for segmented sequences this is *very* fast. The stream iterators use `>>` or `<<` for each element which always checks if the stream is good. For input, it also checks whether the `tie()` needs to be flushed and skips leading whitespace. Even an implementation optimizing these calls will have multiple checks for each individual non-whitespace character.

Comment: The symbolic vernacular was what really caught my eye. I see an `ofstream` and `rdbuf()` (which I've always equated to "read" buffer, obviously incorrectly) and i do a double take. Now you have me curious just how much overhead the regular iterators introduce time-wise. Gonna bench it and see for myself. Thanks again, sir. Oh, and odd as it sounds I'm leaving the mistake of signed char-ness in my post.  think between your answer here, that answer, and your comment to that answer, a reader will actually get more benefit from learning from my mistake than never seeing it at all.

Comment: @DietmarKühl It's simplest than i thought, thanks a lot. And would like to apologize for my stupidity. It's draw lessons to future. I'm newbie here. Once again thank you very much. Nice holidays

Answer (score 1):

You can make this significantly simpler by using the same idea you have for`remove_if`, but instead applying it directly to determining whether to copy at all. something like the code below. Note: not tested, but I hope you get the idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream is("file.csv", ios::in);
    ofstream os("file.txt", ios::out|ios::trunc);
    std::remove_copy_if(
        istream_iterator<char>(is),
        istream_iterator<char>(),
        ostream_iterator<char>(os),
        std::ptr_fun<int,int>(isspace));
    os.close();
    is.close();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I can't believe Deitmar and I had almost identical ideas.

Comment: Well, this just shows that it is somehow the correct solution :-) Note, however, that your code has a subtle but critical mistake: `isspace()` only takes positive values. On a system where `char` is signed and the encoding may yields non-ASCII characters (like the u-umlaut in my name when using ISO Latin-1) it creates undefined behavior! This is the primary reason I'm using an extra function. Also, it isn't necessary to call `close()` on the streams but these are details.

Comment: Excellent point on the signed-ness of char. Never even considered it. Thanks for the tip!. Probably helps when you're constantly being reminded of such nuances with the chars in your very-own name =P